# passing the result of Object.create() as the arg to Object.create() can't working

Tags: javascript

```
var Parent = Object.create(null);

Object.defineProperties(Parent, {
    __name: {
        value: 'tom'
    },
    __age: {
        value: 26
    },
})

var foo =  Object.create(Parent); // {} No Properties
```

Why can't Object.create(Parent)  get the properties __name and __age from Parent

Comment: What do you mean "no properties"? It works fine. Try `foo.__name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't Object.create(Parent) get the properties __name and __age from Parent

It **does**, you're just apparently looking for them via `Object.keys` or similar, which only shows you an object's **own** properties, not ones it inherits from its prototype.

If you use `in` (`"__name" in foo`), you'll see that the property exists, and if you access it, you'll get the value from the prototype.

We can't use `foo.hasOwnProperty` (not directly), because `Parent` has a `null` prototype, instead of the usual `Object.prototype`. So `foo` doesn't inherit the usual things from `Object.prototype`. We can use it *indirectly*, however: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "__name")`. That would say `false` because it's not an own property, it's inherited.

Here's an example, with various ways of detecting the properties and their results (which vary based on whether the way we're looking looks at inherited properties):

```js
var Parent = Object.create(null);

Object.defineProperties(Parent, {
    __name: {
        value: 'tom'
    },
    __age: {
        value: 26
    },
})

var foo = Object.create(Parent);
snippet.log(foo.__name);                                // tom
snippet.log(foo.__age);                                 // 26

snippet.log("__name" in foo);                           // true, it's there
snippet.log(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "__name")); // false, it's inherited
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(foo)));          // [] - object.keys only looks at "own" properties
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Re your comment:

> Why are there no [[proto]] property refer to Parent in foo when debug in devtool

I think you mean `__proto__`, not `[[proto]]`. They're not the same thing. `__proto__` is an *accessor property* that, if present, accesses the object's `[[proto]]`. Chrome's devtools shows you `__proto__` if it's there. But `foo` doesn't have one. Why not? Because `__proto__` is part of `Object.prototype` (see [§B.2.2.1 of the draft spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__)), and `foo` doesn't inherit `Object.prototype`, because it inherits from `Parent` which has no prototype, because it was created via `Object.create(null)`.

We can see that `foo` has a prototype, and that it's `Parent`, by using `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```js
var Parent = Object.create(null);

Object.defineProperties(Parent, {
    __name: {
        value: 'tom'
    },
    __age: {
        value: 26
    },
})

var foo = Object.create(Parent);
snippet.log(foo.__proto__ === Parent);              // false, foo doesn't have __proto__
snippet.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === Parent); // true, Parent is foo's prototype
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are there no [[proto]] property refer to Parent  in foo  when debug in devtool

Comment: I use Chrome's devtools. Thanks a lot. i got it.

Comment: @user2613649: It's **not** a bug in devtools! I've updated the answer to explain why this is correct behavior.